# Return var from another function is JS

Tags: javascript

I read a lot but i think that i'm not getting it.

I read this [duplicated post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) many times, and still can't figure it out how to make work.
I working with code from another person and can't go crazy on the code.

How can i get a callback response to use outside the function?
This code is in a function, that is in another function.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: data
}).done(function(resp){
    res = resp;
});
return res;
```

I get

```
ReferenceError: res is not defined
return res;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define var then u can use it in anywhere in function 
   E.G.  var res;

Comment: I tried, don't work.